# Bounding Box using c in opencv

Tags: c, opencv, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to create a bounding box around each character in an image. I have converted the image to binary and thresholded it but I don't understand how to create a bounding box despite reading the manual.

Comment: I think I've never read a question that bad. DOWNVOTE!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for the bounding box technique, but I think you'll get a great result combining these two:

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206526/how-to-detect-text-area-from-image/10232763#10232763), use the technique [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317919/176769) to detect a large portion of text and put a bounding rectangle around it so you crop the image to this area;
- Second, experiment with the technique [recently presented by OpenCV](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html), also demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10239600/176769). It could be used to locate/extract individual characters on the resulting image of the first step.

I suppose you are trying to implement the OCR mechanism yourself instead of relying on great APIs such as Tesseract.

If you are looking for more information on how to do digit/text recognition, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107970/176769).

Answer (score 0):

As said before "rudely", I encourage you to rewrite your question with more detail on what you already did. We didn't understand what you would like to do. If character recognition is what you want, have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18169-optical-character-recognition-ocr).