# Drawing Bounding-Box using OpenCV in C++ Enviroment

Tags: c++, opencv, bounding-box

Hello peeps I have developed a piece of software that draws contours of the input image, now I wont to take this to the next level and draw Bounding Box around objects of interest i.e. A person. I looked at boundingRect() function but i am struggling to understand it. Maybe there are different functions algorithms draw Bounding Box.....?

Here is the code of my program:

```
     #include "iostream"
    #include<opencv\cv.h>
    #include<opencv\highgui.h>
    #include<opencv\ml.h>
    #include<opencv\cxcore.h>
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <string> 
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat)
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> // Video write

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat image; Mat image_gray; Mat image_gray2; Mat threshold_output;
int thresh=100, max_thresh=255;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //Load Image
    image =imread("C:/Users/Tomazi/Pictures/Opencv/tomazi.bmp");

    //Convert Image to gray & blur it
    cvtColor( image, 
        image_gray, 
        CV_BGR2GRAY );

    blur( image_gray, 
        image_gray2,
        Size(3,3) );
    //Threshold Gray&Blur Image
    threshold(image_gray2, 
        threshold_output, 
        thresh, 
        max_thresh, 
        THRESH_BINARY);

    //2D Container
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;

    //Fnd Countours Points, (Imput Image, Storage, Mode1, Mode2, Offset??)
    findContours(threshold_output,
        contours, // a vector of contours
        CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,// retrieve the external contours
        CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,
        Point(0, 0)); // all pixels of each contours    

    // Draw black contours on a white image
    Mat result(threshold_output.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(255));
    drawContours(result,contours,
        -1, // draw all contours
        Scalar(0), // in black
        2); // with a thickness of 2


        //Create Window
    char* DisplayWindow = "Source";
    namedWindow(DisplayWindow, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(DisplayWindow, result);


    waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}
```

Can anyone suggest an solution...? Perhaps direct me to some sources, tutorials etc. Reading OpenCV documentation and looking at the boundingRect() function i still dont understand. HELP PLEASE :)

Comment: Is your problem how to get the parameters for the bounding box or how to actually draw it using the `rectangle` function?

Comment: both :/ If you could perhaps direct me to some simple source or tutorials or even better if you could explain it to me here. thx

Answer (score 4):

But you can also easily compute the bounding box yourself and then draw them using the `rectangle` function:

```
int maxX = 0, minX = image.cols, maxY=0, minY = image.rows;

for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
    for(int j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
    {
        Point p = contours[i][j];

        maxX = max(maxX, p.x);
        minX = min(minX, p.x);

        maxY = max(maxY, p.y);
        minY = min(minY, p.y);
    }

rectangle( result, Point(minX,minY), Point(maxX, maxY), Scalar(0) );
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) link was not helpful?

I think it demonstrates how to take the contour object and make it a polygon approximation, plus how to draw the bounding rectangle around it.

It seems to be one of the basic OpenCV demos.

Answer (score 1):

I've talked about the bounding box technique in these posts:

- [How to detect Text Area from image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206526/how-to-detect-text-area-from-image/10232763#10232763)
- [Contours opencv : How to eliminate small contours in a binary image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238765/contours-opencv-how-to-eliminate-small-contours-in-a-binary-image/10239600#10239600)
- [OpenCv 2.3 C - How to isolate object inside image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317919/176769) (simple C++ demo)

I think that the last one can probably help you understand how the standard technique works. What OpenCV offers is an easier approach.